# Graphql + Rails 5: update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

Estou tendo alguns problemas na hora de fazer o update dos dados da tabela com o GraphQL.

Situação:
Preciso enviar o campo `description` e o `status` para alteração. Porém nem sempre vai ser necessário mandar os dois.

```
module Mutations
  class UpdateTask < BaseMutation
    argument :id, ID, required: true
    argument :description, String, required: false
    argument :status, String, required: false
    type Types::TaskType
    def resolve(id:, description:, status:)
      task = Task.find(id)
      task.update(description: description, status: status)
    end
  end
end
```

Quando eu faço o envio, ele atualiza os campos mas retorna esse erro:

```
        Failed to implement Task.id, tried:

        - `Types::TaskType#id`, which did not exist
        - `TrueClass#id`, which did not exist
        - Looking up hash key `:id` or `"id"` on `true`, but it wasn't a Hash

        To implement this field, define one of the methods above (and check for typos)
```

Como que eu poderia resolver esse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, o erro não porque você está passando id, description e status nos parâmentros como um hash e não como um símbolo. Onde: Hash você tem { key: value }. No seu método, talvez basta mudar isso:

```
def resolve(:id, :description, :status)
  task = Task.find(id)
  task.update(description: description, status: status)
end
```

Obs: ser for mandar o objeto `task` para uma view por exemplo, não esquece de incluir o @: `@task`. Espero que ajude!